# Verity of Residue theorem of [0,2pi]

Tags: residue-calculus

After I turn 
$$ cos\theta=\frac12(z+\frac1{z})$$and
$$ d\theta=\frac1{iz}dz$$
the denominator become a mess 
$$ \frac{dz}{(a^2+\frac{b^2}4(z^2+2+\frac1{z^2})+\frac{ab}2(z+\frac1z))(iz)}$$
How can a find out the pole?
[image]

Comment: You need to do the algebra. Multiply by $z^2/z^2$ and factor.

Comment: Then it become something like this
$$\frac{4zdz}{i(b^2z^4+2abz^3+(2ab+4a^2)z^2+2abz+b^2)} $$
it is a mess again

Answer (score 1):

If you bring a $z^2$ in to the denominator factor without expanding the squared quantity, you can get something like

$$\frac{z}{\left( a z + \frac{b}{2}(z^2+1)\right)^2}$$

Factor the quadratic term to determine the poles (of order 2) and use the residue theorem.